# Automatic annotation callouts after some zoom level

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I would like to display annotation callouts automatically after a specific zoom level. However, I do not want to have all the annotation callouts, but only those which are being shown in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display annotation callout of those that are visible on screen just the code below should do the trick, as it relies on the `selectAnnotation` method of `MKMapView`, of course, after detecting the desired zoom level:

```
for (MKAnnotation *annotation in mapView.annotations) {
   if ( MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)) ) {
       [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
   }
}
```